# Python - matching integer in filename?

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I'm creating a data file which has an identifier in the first column ('id') containing a name and number (i.e. name22, name43, name185). I'm trying to get the digit in the identifier (from the data file) and match it with the digit in the filenames present in the directory above the current one - those files have a different name but the same corresponding number (i.e. old22, old43, old185).

How can I match the digit in the 'id' column of my data file with the digits in the filenames? I wrote the script below, but I don't get any output/errors.

```
import os
import fnmatch
import pandas as pd

os.system('grep id *log > data.txt')
df = pd.read_table("data.txt", delim_whitespace=True, header = None)
df.columns = ['id','anum','aname','iso']
num = df.id.str.extract('(\d+)')
regex = r'\d+'

for filename in os.listdir('../'):
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(regex,'*.txt'):
         f = open(filename,"r"):
         ...do more things....
```

Comment: Are the numbers always at the end?

Comment: yes, they always have the format nameXXX.

Comment: Are you using the DataFrame for anything other than extracting the numbers from the first column vaules?

Comment: yes, foreach matching file I'd like to grab the interesting columns and match them to the data.txt file using a dictionary.

Comment: What is your Python version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `id` column is like this:

```
f_s = pd.Series(['name22', 'name43', 'name185'])
```

and `os.listdir('../')` is like this:

```
others = ['old22.txt', 'old43.txt', 'old185.txt', 'mold43.png']
```

You can create a set of the numbers in the `id` column

```
id_nbrs = set(f_s.str.extract(r'(\d+)'))
```

Then use a function to filter the files you want:

```
digits = re.compile(r'(\d+)$')
def f(s):
    name, ext = s.split('.')
    nbr = digits.search(name).group()
    #print(name, ext, nbr)
    return nbr in id_nbrs and ext == 'txt'

for thing in filter(f, others):
    print(thing)

>>>
old22.txt
old43.txt
old185.txt
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

> This module provides support for Unix shell-style wildcards, which are not the same as regular expressions (which are documented in the re module). The special characters used in shell-style wildcards are:

```
Pattern     Meaning
*   matches everything
?   matches any single character
[seq]   matches any character in seq
[!seq]  matches any character not in seq
```

[fnmatch docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/fnmatch.html)

This means you cannot use full regular expressions to find a file name, just  shell wildcards. I'd advise to use `*` with an id, e.g. `*123.txt`

```
# assuminng you have id variable
for filename in os.listdir('.'):
  if fnmatch.fnmatch(filename, '*{0}.txt'.format(id)):
     f = open(filename,"r") #...
```

You can also use `fnmatch.filter` function as the solution above is not the most efficient one.